# border Radius for searchbar in nativeScript

Tags: android, nativescript

I have added a search bar to my app by following samples in SDK examples. 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzREq.png)

I am trying to give it rounded corners and gray border. For that I have tried doing something like this:

```
 @ViewChild('searchBarSchool') ngSearchBar: ElementRef;
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.nsSearchBar = this.ngSearchBar.nativeElement;
        this.nsSearchBar.backgroundColor = new Color("pink");
        this.nsSearchBar.borderRadius = "2";
        this.nsSearchBar.borderBottomWidth = 10;
        this.nsSearchBar.borderColor = new Color("gray");

    }
```

And in html,

```
<SearchBar #searchBarSchool hint="Search for school"(textChange)="onTextChange($event)"   
  (loaded)="onSearchBarLoaded($event)"></SearchBar>
```

I can see the background color "pink" taking effect on UI but borderRadius does not work. 
I refereed the SearchBar class borderRadius is indeed one of the property there.

ref: https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_search_bar_.searchbar.html

Can someone help me, I need a rounded borders for my search box.

Comment: Wouldn't the `.nativeElement` property give you the underlying Android/iOS view instance? In which case none of the properties that you are trying to set are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Partial border radiuses are not supported in NativeScript at this very moment.
Meaning that you can set **borderWidth** instead of **borderBottomWidth** and then you will be able to set **borderRadius** (but for all corners). Discussed also [here](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/border-radius-top-left-is-not-working/452/5?u=nickiliev)

Another possibility is discussed [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2152)